# Detect if a SQLAlchemy model has pending write operations associated with it

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have an application in which I query against a SQL database and end up with a SQL Alchemy object representing a given row. Then, based on user input and a series of if/then statements I may perform an update on the SQLA object.

i.e.,

```
if 'fooinput1' in payload:
   sqla_instance.foo1 = validate_foo1(fooinput1)
if 'fooinput2' in payload:
   sqla_instance.foo2 = validate_foo2(fooinput2)
...
```

I now need to add `modified_at` and `modified_by` data to this system. Is it possible to check something on the SQLA instance like `sqla_instance.was_modified` or `sqla_instance.update_pending` to determine if a modification was performed?

(I recognize that I could maintain my own `was_modified` boolean, but since there are many of these if/then clauses that would lead to a lot of boilerplate which I'd like to avoid if possible.)

---

FWIW: this is a python 2.7 pyramids app reading from a MySQL db in the context of a web request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Session object SQL Alchemy ORM provides has two attributes that can help with what you are trying to do:

1) [Session.is_modified()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.is_modified)

2) [Session.dirty](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of fields which modification you want to track you may achieve what you need using [ORM Events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html):

```
@sa.event.listens_for(Thing.foo, 'set')
def foo_changed(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.last_modified = datetime.now()

@sa.event.listens_for(Thing.baz, 'set')
def baz_changed(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.last_modified = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

The session object provides events, which may help you.
just review once,
-->Transient to pending status for session object